# How to add two users in one role in "aspnet_usersinroles"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

Is it possible to add  Two  Users  in One Role in DB?  For exem: I've two users so, I wanna to  add them in Admin Role in DB. How can do  that?

I'm using asp.net MVC5.
In a View, I may call only one User who have a Admin role with  function:

```
@If(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
<p>Test  Admin page!</p>
}
```

Comment: your code sample has nothing to do with how you are trying to create users.

Comment: Start from here http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: do it the same way you added the first admin user to the role - show your code for how you do that. usually, roles are a many to many relationship, so many users can have the same role, and users can have many roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article will be useful for you:

[Working with Roles in ASP.NET Identity for MVC](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc)

If you want to get result directly, so go to your DB and add a new role (if not exists) to AspNetRoles table then add your users to AspNetRoles table with that role's id. This one is simple, manual but fastest for you.

Update:

Due to your new comments: If you just need a little code, probably this one is for you:

```
var user = UserManager.FindByName("YourUserName");
           UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
           context.SaveChanges();
```